# Modificar class en respuesta de AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, class

Necesito que dependiendo de la respuesta de AJAX, cambiar la clase de un SPAN.
No funciona. Aclaro que el AJAX funciona perfecto y devuelve el resultado esperado.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ActivarDesactivar", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var idCliente = <?php echo $id;?>;
 var idSucursal = $(this).closest("tr").find(".id").text();
 
 
 
 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "activadesactiva.php",
            data: {NumeroDeCliente:idCliente, NumeroDeSucursal:idSucursal},
   dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
   var dato = data[0];
      
   if(dato == "ACTIVADO"){
   $(this).addClass("label-success"); 
   } else if(dato == "DESACTIVADO"){
   $(this).addClass("label-danger");    
   }
    

            },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
        })
})
```

```html
<?php
//....

echo '<td align="center" class="activonoactivo" >';
if($ActivoNoActivoSucursal=="ACTIVO"){
 echo '<span class="label label-success ActivarDesactivar">&nbsp;</span>';
 }else{
 echo '<span class="label label-danger ActivarDesactivar">&nbsp;</span>';}
echo'</td>';
echo '<td><span class="AutorizadosBtn label label-info" style="cursor:pointer;">AUT >></span></td>';
echo '</tr>';


//....
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto!
Al parecer $(this) no se puede referenciar directamente en una respuesta de AJAX. Por lo tanto, lo resolví definiendo una variable previamente.

Lo dejo aquí por si alguien lo necesita.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ActivarDesactivar", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var $this = $(this);
 var idCliente = <?php echo $id;?>;
 var idSucursal = $(this).closest("tr").find(".id").text();
 
 
 
 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sucursales_activadesactiva.php",
            data: {NumeroDeCliente:idCliente, NumeroDeSucursal:idSucursal},
   dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
   var dato = data[0];
      
   if(dato == "ACTIVADO"){
   $this.removeClass("label-danger").addClass("label-success"); 
   } else if(dato == "DESACTIVADO"){
   $this.removeClass("label-success").addClass("label-danger");    
   }
    

            },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
        })
})
```